# Backing up an unmounted device to a tar file

Tags: filesystems, mount, tar, aws

Although my overall objectives is to do something on Amazon Web Services (AWS), my specific question is agnostic to AWS.

**Background**

My objective is to use [Packer](https://www.packer.io) to create an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) with several different paths mounted to different filesystems to improve security. E.g. `/tmp` should be mounted to a filesystem with the `noexec` option.

The fact that I want to create an automated process for making an AMI means that I can't execute re-mounting commands in the instance itself, so I am instead using the Packer [amazon-chroot builder](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-chroot.html). This means I run an EC2 Instance, and run Packer from that EC2 Instance. Packer will then mount an EBS Volume taken from an EBS Snapshot used with a "source AMI". I now need to perform some operations on the mounted EBS Volume.

**My Question**

One of my first steps is to take a complete backup of of the block device mounted to `/mnt/ebs`.

According to the excellent presentation at this exact part https://youtu.be/8h_Y-L1Q8xI?t=13m47s, the speaker recommends doing this by first unmounting the device and then using `tar`.

He repeats this order of operations [later in the presentation](http://wernerb.github.io/hashiconf-hardening/#/32). My specific question is: how can I create a tar backup of the contents of a device if it's not mounted in the first place? Also, is the point of unmounting it first to guarantee that it's in a consistent state, that no further writes occur during backup, or something else?

As an aside, I can't seem to unmount the device without the `umount -l` option, despite checking for busy processes using `fuser` or `lsof` but I'll leave those details to another question.

Note that I am using Amazon Linux, which is similar to CentOS but doesn't use systemd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to back up an un-mounted filesystem with tar.

Tar is expecting to back up *files*, but as you suspected, with the filesystem unmounted, the files are unavailable to tar.

Notice that the presenter states:

> ...first we unmount everything **that Packer just mounted for us**...

He didn't state what Packer mounted, but take a close look at that screenshot of the script: it excludes various mount points, such as /proc and /dev. That means *something* is in fact mounted; I'm assuming it's a fake root with the pseudo filesystems bind-mounted.

The ideal way to create a tar-based backup is to mount the filesystem read-only. The purpose is to maintain the integrity of the filesystem while the backup is in progress; You don't want changes being made during the backup process.

It seems like you can take a snapshot of the EBS volume in question, mount it elsewhere as read-only, and then create your tar archive from there.

Comment: Very helpful! The second-to-last paragraph exactly answered my question. Thank you!

Comment: surely if I captured a disk image (dd if=/dev/sda of=/intermediate-storage/sda.img) i could then create a tar archive containing the sda image, I'd like to do this without the intermediate storage device, there's no flag in tar to treat block devices like normal files?